# Add Treeview to ASP.NET MVC with AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a list, with 2 levels, being displayed like this in my vbhtml page:

```
<li>Contract Coverage:</li>
<li ng-repeat="(key, val) in orgSettings">
    <label>{{key}}</label>        
    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="setting in val">{{setting.settingname}}</li>
    </ul> 
</li>
<li>
```

Line 3 represents an org, and multiple settings will be listed underneath (the ng-repeat in line 5).
I'd like to turn this display into a collapsible/expandable treeview at the Org level, so that the settings hide away and can be expanded to show underneath a specific org in the list if the user clicks on a the plus sign next to it.

Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of it is:

```
<li ng-init="visible = {}">Contract Coverage:</li>
<li ng-repeat="(key, val) in orgSettings" ng-init="visible[key]=true" ng-click="visible[key]=!visible[key]" >
    <label>{{key}}</label>        
    <ul ng-show="visible[key]">
       <li ng-repeat="setting in val" >{{setting.settingname}}</li>
    </ul> 
</li>
<li>
```

See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vge0wqV590cCsofUZU05?p=preview